# ProgressDialog shows up after thread is done

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have the following three classes:

When I try to show a progressDialog when the WorkingThread is running, the ProgressDialog only shows up after the WorkingThread is done. What am I doing wrong?

**I am not interested in using an AsyncTask!**

-StartActivity:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    public ProgressDialog pgd;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        pgd = ProgressDialog.show(StartActivity.this, "", "Loading picture"); // Start ProgressDialog before starting activity

        Intent ActivityIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(ActivityIntent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            pgd.dismiss(); //Stop ProgressDialog when FirstActivity is "done"
        }
    }
}
```

-

-FirstActivity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WorkingThread wt = new WorkingThread();
        wt.start();

        try 
        {
            wt.join();
            Intent ActivityIntent = getIntent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, ActivityIntent);
            finish();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

-WorkingThread:

```
public class WorkingThread extends Thread 
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        super.run();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `ProgressDialog` always need **current Activity context** for display.But in your case `ProgressDialog` is little **unfortunate**

The reason is as soon as you fire `ProgressDialog` the next couple of lines take out Context from Current activity and starts Next Activity i.e `FirstActivity`.So your `progressDialog` gets no chance to present itself on the Screen.

Comment: Thx. The Handler class solved the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061281/display-progressdialog-while-listview-is-loading

Answer (score 2):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Here's an example:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog activityProgressDialog;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new TestAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Called before doInBackground.
        //Initialize your progressDialog here.
        activityProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
                "Test",
                "Doing heavy work on background...", false,
                false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {

        //Do your work here
        //Important!!! Update any UI element on preExcecute and
                    //onPostExcecute not in this method or else you will get an 
                    //exception.
        //The below code just make the thread inactive for 5 seconds.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().notify();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        //Dismiss the progessDialog here.
        activityProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

 }
```

I just show your edit that you don't want to use an AsyncTask. I will not delete this answer (unless you want me to) since it is another way of doing what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
        {
            wt.join();
            Intent ActivityIntent = getIntent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, ActivityIntent);
            finish();
        }
```

here is your problem. The UI thread is waiting the Working Thread to finish becaouse of the `join()`.

Comment: If I don't make it wait for the WorkingThread to finish, the ProgressDialog closes instantly and doesn't serve it's purpose?

Comment: @Alex but you do.  The call `wt.join()` insures that you do.

Comment: That's why you should use AsyncTask. Alternatively, you could make a callback interface, and call it from your thread when it is done.

Comment: that's another kind of issue. You are asking why the ProgressDialog is showing after the Working thread is done