# Fix ProgressDialog showing up after download is complete

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` that is populated with articles. When the user long clicks on an article, I want to download its summary and display it to the user. I have a function in `AsyncTask` (NOT `doInBackground`...) that takes care of the download. During the downloading process, I want to display a `ProgressDialog`. Since the download is on the main thread, there is a delay when I long click an article and the `ProgressDialog` shows AFTER the download is complete. How can I get it to show DURING the download?

I have tried these methods but I don't really understand it since I am a beginner in Android Development. The app freezes while its downloading and shows the Dialog after it's done.

[ProgressDialog shows up after thread is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244013/progressdialog-shows-up-after-thread-is-done?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[display progressdialog while listview is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061281/display-progressdialog-while-listview-is-loading)

HomeActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    trendingList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            try {
            ...
            } catch (Exception e) {

                String link = homeLinks.get(position);
            //TASK TO DOWNLOAD SUMMARIES FROM ASYNCTASK
                task.downloadSummary(link);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Background Class

```
public class  BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

 //SHOW DIALOG AND THEN DOWNLOAD SUMMARIES
    public void downloadSummary(String address){

        progress.setMessage("Downloaded summary ");
        progress.show();
        ...
```

Comment: No need to add "solved" to the title, just mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing an AsyncTask you must allocate the 3 dependent methods of this thread, onPreExecute that will allocate your ProgressDialog, the InBackground that put the job you want to perform and the onPostExecute that reotrna the result of your work and you close your progressDialog

It had stayed like this

```
public class  BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progress.setMessage("Downloaded summary ");
    progress.show();
    }

    @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {
    //Ação do Trabalho
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Log.e("Work", "Result "+result);
    }
}
```

it is mandatory the google background method does not like when ignoring this use being an AsysnTask will have to use it. If on the contrary if it is a fast job use a thread invoked with run

Comment: I created a function in AsyncTask that will download content once the user requests it. This takes place on the main thread. My problem is that once the user calls the function, there is a delay and the Dialog shows AFTER it downloads.

Comment: I think I'm confusing myself, Beauty started your work on an async thread, in this whole aync you should start an InBackground method it will run your work, and it set when it ends up running the onPostExecute which in turn will terminate your ProgressDialog, I'm sorry if my english is gone, I'm living here

Comment: I wanted to download data on user request because when I put in the background task, it takes a very long time to download everything. I just want to show the user an animation for downloading instead of having the app freeze for a few seconds

Comment: so the interesting thing would be a thread invoked with runnable.

Comment: Do I ever use it?

Comment: to invoke a thred uses this form:                                                              handler = new Handler();

final Runnable runmethod = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runmethod , 1000);

Comment: I fixed the freezing during download problem by starting a new thread that handles the article summary download from the list view. I decided not to use a Downloading  Progress Bar and instead just used a Toast.

Comment: It is a great option I am also glad you did, any questions can tell me. Don't forget to ask the question.