# how to show progress bar(circle) in an activity having a listview before loading the listview with data

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in my second `activity.OnItemClick` of it I called a webservice and trying to fetch data. And after that I am moving to third activity which also have a `ListView` having description of previous activities `ListView` item.

I want to display a progress dialog before populating this `ListView`.

I don't understand how to do it on `ListView`? Does anybody know how to do it?

My Code-

ThirdActivity.java

```
   package com.google.iprotect;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import com.google.iprotect.layout.TitleBarLayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThirdActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    JSONArray jArray1,jArray2;
    String one,two,three,tablename;
    String color,r;
    JSONObject responseJSON;
    TitleBarLayout titlebarLayout;
    final ArrayList<Tables> arraylist = new ArrayList<Tables>();
    TextView tableName;
    ColorStateList colorStateList1;
    String email1,password1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.thirdactivity);

        ListView lv=getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        tablename=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Table Name");
        email1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
        password1 =getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");

        titlebarLayout = new TitleBarLayout(ThirdActivity.this);
        titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonText("go Back");
        titlebarLayout.setRightButtonText("Logout");
        titlebarLayout.setTitle(tablename);
        titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonSize(70,40);
        titlebarLayout.setRightButtonSize(70,40);
        //titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonLeftDrawable(R.drawable.refresh);

        //titlebarLayout.setRightButtonLeftDrawable(R.drawable.buttonrefresh);
        //titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        //titlebarLayout.setRightButtonBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34,49,64));
        //titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        //titlebarLayout.setRightButtonTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,0));     

        XmlResourceParser parser1 =getResources().getXml(R.color.colorstatelist);


        try {
            colorStateList1 = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser1);
            titlebarLayout.setRightButtonTextColor(colorStateList1);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (v.getId() == R.id.left_button) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email1);
                    intent.putExtra("password", password1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else if (v.getId() == R.id.right_button) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    ThirdActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        };
        titlebarLayout.setLeftButtonOnClickListener(listener);
        titlebarLayout.setRightButtonOnClickListener(listener);


        updateTableList();




    }

    private void updateTableList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //final ProgressDialog pd1=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Calling Webservice", "Waiting...", true, false);

        final ProgressBar pbHeaderProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbHeaderProgress);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                pbHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }



            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                r = invokeWebService1(tablename);
                //pd1.dismiss();

                try {
                    responseJSON = new JSONObject(r);
                    //json reading
                    jArray1 = responseJSON.getJSONArray("FirstThree");//get JSONArray jArray1 from JSONObject with name FirstThree
                    jArray2 = responseJSON.getJSONArray("Color");//get JSONArray jArray2 from JSONOobject with name Color
                    JSONObject json_data1 = null;
                    JSONObject json_data2 = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray1.length(); i++) {
                        json_data1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);//get JSONObject json_data1 from JSONArray at index i;
                        one = json_data1.getString("One");//get value from JSONObject json_data1 with key "One"
                        two = json_data1.getString("Two");
                        three = json_data1.getString("Three");
                        json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
                        color = json_data2.getString("color");//get value from JSONObject json_data2 with key "color"

                        Tables tables = new Tables();
                        //set value to Tables Class
                        tables.column1 = one;
                        tables.column2 = two;
                        tables.column3 = three;
                        tables.tableName=tablename;
                        tables.color=color;
                        //add Tables object into ArrayList<Tables>
                        arraylist.add(tables);

                        Log.i("ONE", json_data1.getString("One"));
                        Log.i("TWO", json_data1.getString("Two"));
                        Log.i("THREE", json_data1.getString("Three"));
                        Log.i("color",""+ json_data2.getString("color"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                pbHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Custom Adapter for ListView
                TableDetailAdapter adaptor = new TableDetailAdapter(ThirdActivity.this,
                        R.layout.table_data_list_item, arraylist);
                setListAdapter(adaptor);
            }
        }.execute();

    }

    protected String invokeWebService1(String tablename2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = "";
        try {
            WebService webService = new WebService(
            "http://sphinx-solution.com/iProtect/api.php?");

            // Pass the parameters if needed
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("action", "getTableRecords");
            params.put("tablename", tablename2);
            params.put("email", email1);
            params.put("password", password1);

            // Get JSON response from server the "" are where the method name
            // would normally go if needed example
            response = webService.WebGet("auth", params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.v("", "Click ListItem Number "+position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,FourthActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Json", responseJSON.toString());//sending json Object as a string to next activity
        intent.putExtra("Table Name", tablename);
        intent.putExtra("email", email1);
        intent.putExtra("password", password1);
        intent.putExtra("Item No", position);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

thirdactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ThirdActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/titlebar"
        layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp" 
        android:layout_weight="5.04">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/footer_bg_color"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            layout="@layout/footer_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you searched about this query on internet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061281/display-progressdialog-while-listview-is-loading

Comment: Pankaj- I know how to display Progressdialog, but I want to display only Progressbar circle instead of progress dialog.

Comment: Check this https://www.freakyjolly.com/show-progress-bar-with-text-and-title-in-android/

Answer (score 176, accepted):

There are several methods of showing a progress bar (circle) while loading an `activity`. In your case, one with a `ListView` in it.

*IN ACTIONBAR*

If you are using an `ActionBar`, you can call the `ProgressBar` like this (this could go in your `onCreate()`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

And after you are done displaying the list, to hide it.

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

*IN THE LAYOUT (The XML)*

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity (Java)
I use an AsyncTask to fetch data for my lists. SO, in the AsyncTask's `onPreExecute()` I use something like this:

```
// CAST THE LINEARLAYOUT HOLDING THE MAIN PROGRESS (SPINNER)
LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {    
    // SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE LOADING FEEDS
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and in the `onPostExecute()`, after setting the adapter to the `ListView`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {     
    // SET THE ADAPTER TO THE LISTVIEW
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // CHANGE THE LOADINGMORE STATUS TO PERMIT FETCHING MORE DATA
    loadingMore = false;

    // HIDE THE SPINNER AFTER LOADING FEEDS
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

EDIT: This is how it looks in my app while loading one of several `ListViews`

[image]

Comment: I have no Actionbar in my application. I want to display proressbar circle at center of the screen.

Comment: @Ani: It's already there in the answer. Use the code example for using in the layout. It also has the code for your XML.

Comment: Its working.But I want this progress circle at center.    If I placed it at center my listview get disturbed.

Comment: @Ani: If you have incorporated my code, update your post with it. I use this code in my entire app and at no point of time does it _disturb_ my listview.

Comment: @Ani: Put your `ProgressBar` in a `LinearLayout` without the `android:layout_weight="2"` attribute. I find it easier to use that way. Then control the `visibility` of that `LinearLayout`

Comment: thats work now. I accept it as answer.  But 1 query is - is it effecient to just changing visibility. I heard that we can solve this issue using viewFlipper.Did u have any knowledge on viewflipper?

Comment: I don't see why changing the visibility twice in one activity can be inefficient. And I don't think you can use a `ViewFlipper` here. Just saying. Someone else might have a different opinion  though.

Comment: findViewById is not defined in AsyncTask... so how then does it pass from the activity to the asynctask?

Comment: @BinaryNights: Which `findViewById` are you referring to?

Comment: from the code snippets you have provided, the line above the `onPreExecute` definition.

Comment: @BinaryNights: It is defined in the XML and cast in the `AsyncTask` before calling the `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: @SiddharthLele the xml part i understood, the function `findViewById` was showing up as not defined.  I must be missing an import.  Thanks.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i am getting an error at this line of code in xml style="@style/Spinner", have you defined you own style?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal: Yes. It is a style. You will find it the SDK from any of the ICS APIs. Search for this XML: `progress_medium_holo.xml` and also copy the relevant images in their respective drawable folders.

Comment: What about SherlockListFragment? How to implement in it.

Comment: @PratikButani: I don't see why it should be any different in a `SherlockListFragment`. Although, truth be told, I have never used one. But the logic is pretty much the same considering that the code is fairly flexible. The same is also used in `GridViews` in the app this example is from.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Thanks for reply but i don't know actually where to define `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`

Comment: @PratikButani: The `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` would go at the start of a method / task that does some activity you want to show the progress of. This should help you figure that part out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10755360/450534

Comment: @PratikButani: If you are using an `AsyncTask`, then you should put the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` and  `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);` in the `onPreExecute()` and finally, in the `onPostExecute()` put this line: `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);`

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthLele i got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157504/put-a-progressbar-on-actionbar/9157874#comment28365016_9157874

Comment: @SiddharthLele Please could you share the style you used in your example?

Comment: @eddy just use style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" in the ProgressBar node

Comment: @Mondain: Yup. That attribute will work. I had to create my own style to make sure the ProgressBar looked the same even on API's below the ICS.

Comment: @IceMAN What if I need to prevent the user from interacting with the items in the action bar? Will `ProgressDialog`  be my only option in that case?

Comment: @Axel: Correct. However, using a `ProgressBar`, there are two ways that result can be achieved. **1:** Use a boolean to flag an ongoing task. Set it to `true` in the onPreExecute() and `false` in the `onPostExecute()`. Check in the `onOptionsItemSelected` if the boolean is `false` and then allow the action to be enabled. **2:** If you are now using a `Toolbar` instead of an `ActionBar`, place it after the `linlaHeaderProgress` shown in the example. This will hide it entirely until the process completes. The _1st_ option can also be used with a `Toolbar`.

Comment: Can u please tell us what is the definition of `@style/Spinner` ?

Answer (score 40):

You can do this easier.
Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_loading_spinner.htm
It helped me.

Layout:

```
<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

> After defining it in xml, you have to get its reference in java file
>   through ProgressBar class. Its syntax is given below:

```
private ProgressBar spinner;
spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

> After that you can make its disappear , and bring it back when needed
>   through setVisibility Method. Its syntax is given below:

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Although this is not the best answer to the question indeed, it helped me to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

I used this one for list view loading may helpful.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Loading data..." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C0C0" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my MainActivity class is,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
LinearLayout layout;
List<String> stringValues;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_view);

    stringValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringValues);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    new Task().execute();
}

class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        stringValues.add("String 1");
        stringValues.add("String 2");
        stringValues.add("String 3");
        stringValues.add("String 4");
        stringValues.add("String 5");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

this activity display progress for 3sec then it will display listview, instead of adding data statically to stringValues list you can get data from server in doInBackground() and display it.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: The Android docs are currently stating that it is not encouraged to use text beneath the progress bar. http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html#activity

Answer (score 9):

Please use the sample at [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progress_circle.htm). The whole implementation only needs a few lines of code without changing your xml file. Hope this helps.

STEP 1: Import library

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
```

STEP 2: Declare ProgressDialog global variable

```
ProgressDialog loading = null;
```

STEP 3: Start new ProgressDialog and use the following properties (please be informed that this sample only covers the basic circle loading bar without the real time progress status).

```
loading = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
loading.setCancelable(true);
loading.setMessage(Constant.Message.AuthenticatingUser);
loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

STEP 4: If you are using AsyncTasks, you can start showing the dialog in onPreExecute method. Otherwise, just place the code in the beginning of your button onClick event.

```
loading.show();
```

STEP 5: If you are using AsyncTasks, you can close the progress dialog by placing the code in onPostExecute method. Otherwise, just place the code before closing your button onClick event.

```
loading.dismiss();
```

Tested it with my Nexus 5 android v4.0.3. Good luck!

Comment: ProgressDialog has been deprecated since API Level O https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 8):

Are you extending ListActivity?

If so, put a circular progress dialog with the following line in your xml

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@android:id/empty"
...other stuff...
/>
```

Now, the progress indicator will show up till you have all your listview information, and set the Adapter.  At which point, it will go back to the listview, and the progress bar will go away.

Comment: I want to display proressbar circle at center of the screen.If I add Progress bar where can I put listview in XML.

Comment: Make a layout like normal.  I did this exact thing on one of my apps.  If I recall, you can put the listview inside a full screen relative layout with height and width of `fill_parent`.  Then as a second child to that relative_layout, have the progress indicator centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: can you have that xml for this.

Comment: But what if the result of the load is empty?

Answer (score 3):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Example.this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

Comment: This is a very simple way to achieve the goal. like K.I.S.S Keep It Simple Stupid way :D

Comment: This is deprecated in API 26.

Answer (score 2):

Create an xml file any name (say progressBar.xml) in drawable
        and add `<color name="silverGrey">#C0C0C0</color>` in color.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="6"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="200dip"
            android:width="300dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/silverGrey"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Now in your xml file where you have your listView add this code:

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_form_statusMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circularprogress"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

In AsyncTask in the method:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressbar_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // your code
}
```

And in onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    progressbar_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `ProgressBar` to listview footer:

```
private ListView listview;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

...

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, null);

listview.addFooterView(progressBar);
```

layout/progress_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
     />
```

when the data is loaded to the adapter view call:

```
        listview.removeFooterView(progressBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you when working with listview or recyclerview to use *SwipeRefreshLayout*. Like this

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Only wrap your view and this will create an animation of refresh when loading data or by swipping down the screen as we can do in many apps.
Here's the documentation of how to use it:
https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html
https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/respond-refresh-request.html

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Use this within button onClick option or your needs.

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..."); // Setting Message
progressDialog.setTitle("ProgressDialog"); // Setting Title
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Process Bar:

Dependency:

```
     implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
```

XML:

```
     <fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myProcessbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

In Res->color

```
      <color name="pocket_color_1">#ff1635</color>
      <integer-array name="pocket_background_colors">
          <item>@color/pocket_color_1</item>
      </integer-array>

      <color name="pocket_color_stop">#00ff00</color>
      <integer-array name="pocket_background_stop">
          <item>@color/pocket_color_stop</item>
      </integer-array>
```

In Main:

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        SmoothProgressBar smoothProgressBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          smoothProgressBar=findViewById(R.id.myProcessbar);
          showProcessBar();
          stopAnimation();    // call when required to stop process
        }

        public void showProcessBar(){
          smoothProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          smoothProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new SmoothProgressDrawable.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .interpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
            .progressiveStart(true)
            .progressiveStopSpeed(1000)
            .build());
          smoothProgressBar.setSmoothProgressDrawableBackgroundDrawable(
          SmoothProgressBarUtils.generateDrawableWithColors(
                    getResources().getIntArray(R.array.pocket_background_colors),
                    ((SmoothProgressDrawable)  smoothProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()).getStrokeWidth()));
        }

        public void stopAnimation(){
          smoothProgressBar.setSmoothProgressDrawableBackgroundDrawable(
          SmoothProgressBarUtils.generateDrawableWithColors(
                    getResources().getIntArray(R.array.pocket_background_stop),
                    ((SmoothProgressDrawable)  smoothProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()).getStrokeWidth()));
          smoothProgressBar.progressiveStop();
          Handler handler=new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               smoothProgressBar.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(6000).translationY(1000);
               smoothProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
          },1000);
}

      }
```

Answer (score -2):

I am using this:

```
loading = ProgressDialog.show(example.this,"",null, true, true);
```