# Progressbar hidden before page loaded in android studio

Tags: java, android, webview, progress-bar

I have a problem with android studio I created a fragment contains webview and progressbar the progress bar disappeared before the url in the web view loaded how to solve this problem?
This is the java class file

```
public class FacebookPage extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    WebView myWebView;
    WebSettings webSettings;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_page,container,false);                
        return myView;
    };

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String url="https://www.facebook.com/TahrirLounge/";
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
                view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_facebook_page).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
}
```

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_facebook_page"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I also now have this error at the log:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.mostafa.tahrirlounge, PID: 8952
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:109)
                                                                            at android.app.ProgressDialog.(ProgressDialog.java:77)
                                                                            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:110)
                                                                            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
                                                                            at com.mostafa.tahrirlounge.FacebookPage.(FacebookPage.java:24)
                                                                            at com.mostafa.tahrirlounge.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:156)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

Comment: Can you also show your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public class FacebookPage extends Fragment {

    WebView webView;

    ProgressDialog progress;
    @Nullable
    @Override  
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_page, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/TahrirLounge/");

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading",
                    "Loading", true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progress != null)
                    progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return mainView;


    }
```

Comment: There is a problem with "this" in the progressbar.show

Comment: use getActivity() instead of "this".

Comment: I changed it but now when I try to open the fragment the application closed

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.mostafa.tahrirlounge, PID: 21030
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at ...

Comment: bro post the complete error(which is in red in log) after "reference at" so that i can better understand. You can use pastebin to share the log if you cant share in comments.

Comment: And there is One more thing... there is difference between progressBar  and progressDialog.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339119/what-is-the-difference-between-progressbar-and-progressdialog

Comment: Alright, its getting worse.just upload the full source code.