# I am trying to figure out how to have a progress bar that says "Loading. Please Wait..." while my audio stream player prepares a streaming file

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class StreamingMediaPlayer {

private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER = 96 * 10 / 8;// assume
// 96kbps*10secs/8bits
// per byte

private TextView textStreamed;

private ImageView playButton;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

// Track for display by progressBar
private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;

private int totalKbRead = 0;

// Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private File downloadingMediaFile;

private boolean isInterrupted;

private Context context;

private int counter = 0;

public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context context, TextView textStreamed,
        ImageView playButton, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.context = context;
    this.textStreamed = textStreamed;
    this.playButton = playButton;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}

/**
 * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the
 * MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
 */
public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long mediaLengthInKb,
        long mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException {

    this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
    this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                        "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl="
                                + mediaUrl, e);
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
}

/**
 * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the
 * setDataSource for that local file
 */
public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

    URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
    cn.connect();
    InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
    if (stream == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
    }

    downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
            "downloadingMedia.dat");

    // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or
    // something, we also delete any previously
    // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh. If you use this code,
    // always delete
    // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk
    // memory. Of course, you can also
    // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for
    // instant replay if you wanted as well.
    if (downloadingMediaFile.exists()) {
        downloadingMediaFile.delete();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
    int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
    do {
        int numread = stream.read(buf);
        if (numread <= 0)
            break;
        out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        totalBytesRead += numread;
        incrementalBytesRead += numread;
        totalKbRead = totalBytesRead / 1000;

        testMediaBuffer();
        fireDataLoadUpdate();
    } while (validateNotInterrupted());
    stream.close();
    if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
        fireDataFullyLoaded();
    }
}

private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {
    if (isInterrupted) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            // mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
 * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to
 * so perform this using a Handler.
 */
private void testMediaBuffer() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                // Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum
                // buffered data
                if (totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        startMediaPlayer();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                                "Error copying buffered conent.", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (mediaPlayer.getDuration()
                    - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000) {
                // NOTE: The media player has stopped at the end so transfer
                // any existing buffered data
                // We test for < 1second of data because the media player
                // can stop when there is still
                // a few milliseconds of data left to play
                transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void startMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
                + (counter++) + ".dat");

        // We double buffer the data to avoid potential read/write errors
        // that could happen if the
        // download thread attempted to write at the same time the
        // MediaPlayer was trying to read.
        // For example, we can't guarantee that the MediaPlayer won't open a
        // file for playing and leave it locked while
        // the media is playing. This would permanently deadlock the file
        // download. To avoid such a deadloack,
        // we move the currently loaded data to a temporary buffer file that
        // we start playing while the remaining
        // data downloads.
        moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length() + "");

        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);

        // We have pre-loaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so
        // update the buttons & progress meters.
        mediaPlayer.start();
        startPlayProgressUpdater();
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.",
                e);
        return;
    }
}

private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile) throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what
                    + ") with extra (" + extra + ")");
            return false;
        }
    });

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    mPlayer.prepare();
    return mPlayer;
}

/**
 * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer. NOTE: Interacting with a
 * MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so
 * this method should always be called using a Handler.
 */
private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        // First determine if we need to restart the player after
        // transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
        boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.
        // Store the old File for deleting later.
        File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),
                "playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
        File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "playingMedia"
                + (counter++) + ".dat");

        // This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on
        // exit. If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything. If
        // you want to
        // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write
        // caching code and please send me a copy.
        bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();
        moveFile(downloadingMediaFile, bufferedFile);

        // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start
        // a new one. So far (Android v1.5),
        // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've
        // stopped the player and started a new one
        mediaPlayer.pause();

        // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior
        // one.
        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

        // Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was
        // previously playing.
        // NOTE: We test for < 1second of data because the media player can
        // stop when there is still
        // a few milliseconds of data left to play
        boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration()
                - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
        if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no
        // longer needed.
        oldBufferedFile.delete();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);
    }
}

private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            textStreamed.setText((totalKbRead + "Kb"));
            float loadProgress = ((float) totalKbRead / (float) mediaLengthInKb);
            progressBar.setSecondaryProgress((int) (loadProgress * 100));
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

            // Delete the downloaded File as it's now been transferred to
            // the currently playing buffer file.
            downloadingMediaFile.delete();
            textStreamed
                    .setText(("Audio full loaded: " + totalKbRead + " Kb read"));
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
    return mediaPlayer;
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    float progress = (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) / mediaLengthInSeconds);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) (progress * 100));

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    }
}

public void interrupt() {
    playButton.setEnabled(false);
    isInterrupted = true;
    validateNotInterrupted();
}

/**
 * Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
 */
public void moveFile(File oldLocation, File newLocation) throws IOException {

    if (oldLocation.exists()) {
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(oldLocation));
        BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
        try {
            // byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
            /* changing the size of the buffer */

            byte[] buff = new byte[16384];

            int numChars;
            while ((numChars = reader.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buff, 0, numChars);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException("IOException when transferring "
                    + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                    + newLocation.getPath());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),
                        "Error closing files when transferring "
                                + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                                + newLocation.getPath());
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException(
                "Old location does not exist when transferring "
                        + oldLocation.getPath() + " to "
                        + newLocation.getPath());
    }
}

public void change_volume(float vol) {
    Log.i("Media Player volume change", "Success" + vol);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(vol, vol);
}

public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}

public void stoppreviousPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        // mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

}

second class  ------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class Play_Radio extends Activity 
{

        private ImageView playButton;

        private TextView textStreamed, tv_radio_name, tv_radio_cat;
    private boolean isPlaying;
    private static StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;
    ImageView iv_like;
    Dialog rankDialog;
    RatingBar ratingBar, pre_rating;
    float cus_rating;
    AdView adView;
    public static String name, rating, like, radio_url, id, listner, image;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_radio);

        /*
         * LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater(); View layout =
         * li.inflate(R.layout.customtoast, (ViewGroup)
         * findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)); Toast toast = new
         * Toast(getApplicationContext()); toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         * toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
         * toast.setView(layout); toast.show();
         */

        // AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        // adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        // adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        //

        // For listner count
        /*
         * 
         * HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost httppost =
         * new HttpPost(
         * "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/radio_listner.php"); try { //
         * Add your data List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
         * ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); nameValuePairs.add(new
         * BasicNameValuePair("id", Tab_Listner.id)); httppost.setEntity(new
         * UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); ResponseHandler<String>
         * responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); String response =
         * httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
         * 
         * // This is the response from a php application String reverseString =
         * response; Log.i("response", reverseString);
         * 
         * } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { Log.i("CPE response ",
         * e.toString()); // TODO Auto-generated catch block } catch
         * (IOException e) { Log.i("IOException response ", e.toString()); //
         * TODO Auto-generated catch block }
         */
        if (audioStreamer != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("Already ply", "Succss");
                audioStreamer.stop();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("First time", "Play");

        }
        initControls();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("On Pause is call", "Succcess");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Log.i("Device Versoin is", "" + currentapiVersion);
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            Log.i("Android Device above", "Home Enbled");
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.i("Home", "Press");
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // protected void onDestroy()
    // {
    // super.onDestroy();
    //
    //
    // if ( audioStreamer != null)
    // { audioStreamer.interrupt();
    // }
    //
    // }

    private void initControls() {
        iv_like = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_activity_like);
        iv_like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Vibrator v1 = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v1.vibrate(40);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Thanks For like Our Station", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                // Like increament
                /*
                 * HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost
                 * httppost = new HttpPost(
                 * "http://www.vaibhavtech.com/work/android/radio_like.php");
                 * 
                 * try { // Add your data List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =
                 * new ArrayList<NameValuePair>( 1); nameValuePairs.add(new
                 * BasicNameValuePair("id", Tab_Listner.id));
                 * 
                 * 
                 * 
                 * httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 * 
                 * // Execute HTTP Post Request
                 * 
                 * ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new
                 * BasicResponseHandler(); String response =
                 * httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                 * 
                 * // This is the response from a php application String
                 * reverseString = response; Log.i("response", reverseString);
                 * 
                 * } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { Log.i("CPE response ",
                 * e.toString()); // TODO Auto-generated catch block } catch
                 * (IOException e) { Log.i("IOException response ",
                 * e.toString()); // TODO Auto-generated catch block }
                 */
            }
        });
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        textStreamed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_kb_streamed);

        playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Click sadg   ", "success");

                Vibrator v1 = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v1.vibrate(40);
                if (audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                    Log.i("play ", "success");
                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_radio_play);
                } else {
                    Log.i("pause", "success");
                    audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();
                    audioStreamer.startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_radio_pause);
                }
                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            }
        });

        // rating radio sation

        ImageView rankBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_activity_rating);
        rankBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rankDialog = new Dialog(Play_Radio.this,
                        R.style.FullHeightDialog);
                rankDialog.setContentView(R.layout.rating_bar);
                rankDialog.setCancelable(true);
                ratingBar = (RatingBar) rankDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialog_ratingbar);
                float userRankValue = 0;
                // ratingBar.setRating(userRankValue);
                ratingBar
                        .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                    float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                cus_rating = rating;

                            }
                        });

                Button updateButton = (Button) rankDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.rank_dialog_button);
                updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Play_Radio.this,
                                "Thanks For Rating Our Stations",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        /*
                         * HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         * HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                         * "http://www.vaibhavtech.com/work/android/radio_rat.php"
                         * );
                         * 
                         * try { // Add your data List<NameValuePair>
                         * nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>( 3);
                         * nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",
                         * Tab_Listner.id)); nameValuePairs.add(new
                         * BasicNameValuePair("rate", "" + cus_rating));
                         * nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", ""
                         * + 2)); httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                         * nameValuePairs));
                         * 
                         * // Execute HTTP Post Request
                         * 
                         * ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new
                         * BasicResponseHandler(); String response =
                         * httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                         * 
                         * // This is the response from a php application String
                         * reverseString = response; Log.i("response",
                         * reverseString);
                         * 
                         * } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                         * Log.i("CPE response ", e.toString()); // TODO
                         * Auto-generated catch block } catch (IOException e) {
                         * Log.i("IOException response ", e.toString()); // TODO
                         * Auto-generated catch block }
                         */
                        rankDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                // now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it
                rankDialog.show();
            }
        });

        String urlstring2 = Tab_Listner.radio_url;
        Toast.makeText(Play_Radio.this,
                "Please Wait ...Radio Is Gonna To Play...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        startStreamingAudio(urlstring2);
        tv_radio_cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_play_radio_cat);
        tv_radio_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_play_radio_name);
        tv_radio_name.setText(Tab_Listner.name);
        pre_rating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        pre_rating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Tab_Listner.rating));
    }

    private void startStreamingAudio(String urlstring) {
        try {
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            if (audioStreamer != null) {
                audioStreamer.interrupt();
            }
            audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, textStreamed,
                    playButton, progressBar);
            audioStreamer.startStreaming(urlstring, 5208, 216);
            // streamButton.setEnabled(false);
            // playButton.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", e);
        }

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.calculator, R.drawable.calendar,
            R.drawable.camera };

    private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.calculator, R.drawable.calendar,
            R.drawable.camera };

}
```

how to add progress bar spinner in this code. spinner work like youtube after then buffering start its stop. plz help me.i am already add progress bar but they can not working now. plz check tuneup on google play.[enter link description here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tuneup.target.myradioapp&hl=en)

Comment: not clear what do you mean by `after then burring start its stop`

Comment: what is burring? i don't understand do you mean buffering?

Comment: @Abhishek Maheshwari Are you asking for loader need to show upto `audioStreamer.startStreaming(urlstring, 5208, 216);` completion?

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari i din't understand your question nor your comment. pls state clearly what is wrong? dialoag/spinner/buffering????

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari you want to show progress dialog when your audio buffers and on completion dismiss it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari Sorry i did not worked like your requirement

Comment: @@AbhishekMaheshwari Please come to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34610/tamil-android i have some doubts

Comment: @AbhishekMaheshwari see this http://pastie.org/8436294.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML add a progress bar element, then hide/show this element when you want to see the progress bar.

```
    <!-- Show spinner by default and set to 'gone' when load is complete -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Hiding the progress bar in your code:

```
ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

.. show again with:

```
pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You can make those calls around the same time you show your toast messages that the load has started.

Comment: ok thanks but i want something more calls around the time when song play

Comment: Oh I see, maybe use this API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html

Comment: Or this state diagram might help... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html You could show a progressbar when starting and hide it after the prepared state finishes.

Comment: I think I got it, show the progress dialog, call prepare() on the mediastream, and then override the mediastream.onPrepared() listener to hide the progress dialog.