# Show Progress bar while downloading

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to show a progress bar showing percentage completed while my app is downloading some big files over the internet.
something like this :[image]

Comment: this is the customized one.

Comment: Have you made this @Hieu le

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xml file code:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/xml_reg_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/common_left_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/common_left_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reg_ph_linear_top_margin"
        />
```

you can change progressbar style as per your requirement.

this is java file code:

```
 protected static final int TIMER_RUNTIME = 180000; // in ms --> 10s
    private ProgressBar progressTimer;
    public void startTimer() {
            final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mbActive = true;
                    try {
                        int waited = 0;
                        while (mbActive && (waited < TIMER_RUNTIME)) {
                            sleep(1000);
                            if (mbActive) {
                                waited += 1000;

                                updateProgress(waited);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {
                        onContinue();
                    }
                }

            };
            timerThread.start();

        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        private void onContinue() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    txtCallContactUsNumber
                            .setText(CommonVariable.CallForSupporMessage
                                    + contactInfo.MobileNo);

                }
            });

        }

        public void updateProgress(final int timePassed) {
            if (null != progressTimer) {
                // Ignore rounding error here
                final int progress = progressTimer.getMax() * timePassed
                        / TIMER_RUNTIME;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i("timePassed", "timePassed=" + timePassed);

                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timePassed);
                        String timer = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
                        formatter.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        txtTimerCount.setText(formatter.format(timePassed));
                    }
                });

                progressTimer.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
```

in my code this will call 1 second and get progress increment every 1 second.

Answer (score 3):

You can acheive this by using a progress bar in two ways.

1.Add a progress bar(the circle one) to act as a loading indicator.

To do this simple show a progress bar on start of the image download thread `progressbar.show();`
After the download is finished dismiss the progressbar `progressbar.dismiss();`

You can use AsyncTask for this

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559461/how-to-show-progress-barcircle-in-an-activity-having-a-listview-before-loading)

2.Add a progress bar(the rectangular bar type) to show the progress of the download or what ever it may be.

I would recomend you to go through this [link](http://androidituts.com/android-progress-bar-tutorial/)..

Answer (score 2):

Check these links:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/

[Show ProgressDialog Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814821/show-progress-dialog-android)

Clearly, explains how to implement the `ProgressBar` or `ProgressDialog`

Here's a good library for customized ProgressDialog:

https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar

https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Comment: ProgressDialog has been deprecated since API Level O https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Progress bar.
I assume for downloading file you are using Asynctask, if you are not then i recommend you to do that.
Async task has has two more cool methods apart from the

> doInBackground()

They are

> preExecute and postExecute

You can override these method, now create a simple progress bar and start it in preExecute and end it in postExecute method.
Here is the working [LINK](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)