# Adding loader at the footer into the listview

Tags: android, android-loader

I am building an android application in which I am implementing pagination for the retrieving of data and showing the data in list view. now the scenario is that I want to insert loader at the the footer or the end of the list view which loads the data and after the completion of loading of  the data it should hide automatically.

Comment: try https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. sorry to say you that it did not worked for me.. actually i want to insert a progress bar at the footer of the list view so which i can fetch the data during pagination; and after loading of the data it should hide. i hope now you can get my problem

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the best way to do it, but you can put both the ListView and the ProgressIndicator in a LinearLayout.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559461/how-to-show-progress-barcircle-in-an-activity-having-a-listview-before-loading) will give you some ideas